# How do I send data from react js to backend express (React and Express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So in my React app I have a button that opens the camera and takes a picture , I want to send that picture to the backend. Below is my code

React js code

```
const DetectDisPage = () => {

  //State to render Camera when button is clicked
  const [cameraIsOpen , setCameraIsOpen] = useState(false);

  //State to maintain capture
  const [isCapture , setIsCapture] = useState(false);

  //Function to open camera
  const openCamera = () => {
    setCameraIsOpen(true)
  }

   //Function to close camera
   const closeCamera = () => {
    setCameraIsOpen(false)
  }

  //Confirming picture and if button is clicked should save image in database
  const confirmPicture =  () => {
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO INSERT THE CODE TO SEND TO BACKEND
  }
  
  //Web Component
  const WebcamComponent = () => <Webcam />;

  const [imgSrc , setImgSrc] = useState(null)

  const webcamRef = useRef(null)

  const capture = useCallback(() => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    setImgSrc(imageSrc);
    setIsCapture(true);
    setCameraIsOpen(false)

  }, [webcamRef, setImgSrc]);


  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />

      <div className={styles.mainCont}>
        <p>Take a picture of suspected Plant or Crop</p>

        {isCapture ? 
          <div className = {styles.cameraCont}> 
            <p onClick= {confirmPicture}>Confirm Picture</p>
          </div>
          :
          <div className= {styles.cameraCont}>
          {
            cameraIsOpen ? 
            <p onClick= {closeCamera}>Close Camera</p>
            :
            <p onClick= {openCamera}>Open Camera</p>
          }
          
        </div>
        }
        
{
  cameraIsOpen ? 
  <div className = {styles.webCamCont}> 
    <Webcam 
    audio={false} 
    ref={webcamRef} 
    screenshotFormat="image/jpeg" /> 
    
    <div className= {styles.captureButtonCont}>
      <button className= {styles.captureButton} onClick={capture}>Take picture</button> 
    </div>
    
    </div> 
    
    : null
}

    {imgSrc && (
        <img
          src={imgSrc}
        />
      )}


      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default DetectDisPage
```

Here is my backend assuming I want to send it to the route and my backend is listening on port 4000

```
app.get('/saveImg' , (req ,res) => {

}
```

I want it so that when i click the "Confirm Picture" button it sends it to that route , I want to send the imgSrc to that backend route. What must I do because anything I put in the function for the Confirm Picture button is not working , must I useEffect anything? I am a beginner at React so any help is highly appreciated.

I also tried a simple console.log for the when the confirm button is clicked but it never showed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here multiple solutions you can follow but for sending data back from frontend you have to use **POST** request for getting you have to use **GET** bit in both ways you can get response from server either a message or data so what you have to do is

```js
const sendDatatoBackend = () => {
axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/api/url/thiscanbeanything",
  data: {
    image: image:path, //here you can add data as an object
  },
})
.then(res => {
  console.log("res", res.data.message);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("error in request", err);
});
}
// you can call this function on button click
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use fetch to send data from your react app to backend

```
const confirmPicture = async () => {
 const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/saveImg", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    // here write your data to send
  }),
 });
 const data = await response.json();
 console.log(data); 
};
```

but you use in your api /saveImg **GET** method to send a data, you should modofied to **POST** method.

Comment: Got this error back - Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 and when i make the backend a .post and i console.log(req.body) I get an empty object @hazem brayek

Comment: did you add your data in body object ?

Comment: yes in the part where you said i should put the data i put imgSrc (Which is the screenshot taken after Take Picture button is clicked